# The right place for `wait` in nested bash loops?

Tags: bash, for-loop, wait

I have tailored my jobs so that 4 of them each work nicely on a 4-vcpu
instance, and have a bash script that launches  4 processes for each of them:

```
for pidx in {0..3}; do
    prname=$1"-"$pidx
    echo "start java" `date` $prname
    { (java -server -Xmx4g -jar $JARPATH "$prname" $DATADIR) } &
    sleep 10; echo "end sleep" $prname `date` 
done
```

Now I want to be able to queue up several such jobs, *waiting for all four
processes to finish* before I launch the next set of 4.  Here's one attempt:

```
TSTJOBS="job1 job2"
for JNAME in $TSTJOBS; do
    echo "startloop "  $(date +%T) $JNAME $$
    for pidx in {0..3}; do
        (
        prname=$JNAME"-"$pidx
        echo "start java" $prname $(date +%T) $!
        (java -server -Xmx4g -jar $JARPATH "$prname" $DATADIR) &
        pid=$!
        sleep 10; echo "end java  " $prname $(date +%T) $pid
        )
        wait $pid
      done
    echo "eoloop    "  $(date +%T) $JNAME 
done
```

I've tried several places for grabbing the processID and for the `wait` command but either:

- I wait for *all 8 sub-jobs to terminate before proceeding,
- *all* jobs are run simultaneously, or
- I get "pid XXX is not a child of this shell" errors?

Where should I be putting the wait statements in these nested loops?

Comment: When you set `pid` in a subshell, it's lost when that subshell exits. So your `wait $pid` is instead just running `wait` with no arguments at all. (You'd get a proper error explaining this to you if you'd used `wait "$pid"` instead).

Comment: What's the purpose of all these subshells, anyhow? What do you intend to accomplish by them?

Comment: ...mind, if I were responsible for writing code to run four jobs at once, I'd be using `xargs -P 4` for it instead of trying to do it by hand in the first place.

Comment: The inner loop subshells are to allow multiple concurrent java runs.  The outer loop is designed to wait for all of the java's to finish before starting on the next job

Comment: You don't need subshells "to allow multiple concurrent java runs".

Comment: Compare your original code `{ (java -server -Xmx4g -jar $JARPATH "$prname" $DATADIR) } &` to the simpler, faster replacement `java -server -Xmx4g -jar $JARPATH "$prname" $DATADIR &`. No explicit subshells, still works just as well -- works _better_ in fact, because you're storing the PIDs of the Java process itself instead of the bash process that starts them.

Comment: If you care more about having the shell write start and end messages than you do about having access to the real PIDs, then keep the subshells, but background _only the subshells themselves_, and not the Java processes within them.

Comment: thx @CharlesDuffy,  so I don't need the inner subshells.  but i still need some (subshell?) to wait for all the java's to finish, yea? (and re: xargs, the `-P 4` is only part of the spec that each instance runs

Comment: The only subshells you strictly, unambiguously need are the ones implicitly created by use of `&`. There's no reason to wrap them in additional explicit subshells.

Comment: ...I don't understand what you mean in the "re: xargs" part of the comment above.

Comment: if you must wait for all 4x jobs to finish before starting the next 4x jobs then place a `wait` (no pid) after the `done` of inner loop and before the `done` of the outer loop; if you want to 'load balance' (ie, have 4 jobs running at all times) then generate a list of all jobs and feed to `parallel` or `xargs` (or write a custom control loop) ... lots of Q&As in SO (and sister sites) re: running parallel jobs (without overloading the host's resources)

Comment: i don't think `xarg` works for my case; in any case it's tangential to my  question regarding `wait` placement

Comment: ...note that there's a lot of room to make your job specifications fed to xargs' input have whatever information you need them to -- form a string, pass it through xargs, parse it back out into the individual components on the other side.

Comment: which is to say, if you described your case in enough detail, I'm basically certain I _could_ show you how to apply xargs to it (though I can't promise to be here monitoring this site for much of the near future). And it's not tangential at all, because with `xargs`, it's the xargs program that does the `wait`s for you, so you don't need a wait anywhere in your shell script in the first place.

Comment: So, let's say you need to pass each copy of the Java program a data directory and a job number. Pipe a loop that invokes `printf '%d %s\0', "$jobnum" "$data_dir"` into `xargs -P4 -n1 -0 bash -c 'jobnum=${1%% *}; data_dir=${1#* }; java ... "$jobnum" "$data_dir"' _` and there you are -- four copies of java running at a time continuously until all your data is done processing. There are ways to tune that to pay less shell startup overhead, but if you're running a JVM over and over that overhead is probably inconsequential.

Comment: ok, i am just ignorant about xargs and its management of wait.  but trying your "...if you must wait for all 4x jobs to finish before starting the next 4x jobs then place a wait (no pid) after the done of inner loop and before the done of the outer loop" suggestions just launches all 8x jobs?

Comment: That was markp-fuso's suggestion, not mine; and before applying it you need to fix the excessive subshells -- `wait` only waits for _direct_ children, not grandchildren.

Comment: make the (easy) fix sugggested by CharlesDuffy (ie, remove the subshell wrappers) first then consider ... your inner loop only starts 4x jobs so if you place `wait` after the inner loop's `done` then you'll wait for those 4x jobs to complete before running the next iteration of the outer loop

Comment: simple as that, `wait` between the two `done` s!  and indeed it worked as intended after I removed all the excess subshell junk.  now how do we make your comments  @markp-fuso  an answer I can pick?  Thanks very much to you and Charles in any case.

Comment: BTW, I think this is implicit in what markp-fuso was telling you, but to spell it out explicitly -- unless your jobs all take the exact same amount of time you're going to have some wasted CPU time here: when the first job in a batch finishes the CPU that was running it is idle until the last job finishes and `wait` can return for the next batch to start. That's one of the problems that `xargs -P` or `parallel` can fix.

Comment: understood @CharlesDuffy.  i will dig into `xargs`  thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a function to take care of the individual job details, eg:

```
run_job() {
    prname="$1-$2"
    echo "start java $prname $(date +%T)"
    java -server -Xmx4g -jar "$JARPATH" "$prname" "$DATADIR"
    echo "end java $prname $(date +%T)"
}
```

Now the main script becomes:

```
TSTJOBS="job1 job2"

for JNAME in $TSTJOBS; do
    echo "startloop  $(date +%T) $JNAME"

    for pidx in {0..3}; do
        run_job "${JNAME}" "${pidx}" &               # place function call in background; NOTE: all function output will print to console so you'll get a mix of 4x sets of output spewed to the console
    done

    wait                                             # wait for all 4x function calls to complete before running next iteration of outer loop
    echo "eoloop     $(date +%T) $JNAME"
done
```

---

If for some reason you can't (or don't want to) use the function you can accomplish the same thing inline, eg:

```
for JNAME in $TSTJOBS; do
    echo "startloop  $(date +%T) $JNAME"

    for pidx in {0..3}; do
        { prname="$1-$2"
          echo "start java $prname $(date +%T)"
          java -server -Xmx4g -jar "$JARPATH" "$prname" "$DATADIR"
          echo "end java   $prname $(date +%T)"
        } &
    done

    wait
    echo "eoloop     $(date +%T) $JNAME"
done
```

Or since you really only need to match ending `echo` calls with the associated `java` call, a mix will also suffice, eg:

```
for JNAME in $TSTJOBS; do
    echo "startloop  $(date +%T) $JNAME"

    for pidx in {0..3}; do
        prname="$1-$2"
        echo "start java $prname $(date +%T)"
        { java -server -Xmx4g -jar "$JARPATH" "$prname" "$DATADIR"
          echo "end java   $prname $(date +%T)"
        } &
    done

    wait
    echo "eoloop     $(date +%T) $JNAME"
done
```

Comment: thanks!  and yes, i realize the stdout will be a muddle across the 4 jobs

Comment: BTW, if the stdout-being-a-muddle thing is a problem for you, that's actually a reason to consider `parallel` instead of xargs. I mostly stay clear of parallel (its design has a lot of extra complexity added in service to features not everyone uses -- most particularly, to support for running jobs over ssh in a manner consistent with how it starts local jobs, it runs a child shell even for those local tasks); but collating each child process's output is one of the features it provides.